# Yii2 Add ActiveRecord Model Attribute

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

In Yii2 I have an ActiveRecord model already created, based on a MySQL table, but I had to add a new column to the table, and I don't know which change should I do to the Yii2 model in order to be able to use this new column.

I tried adding "public $columnname" to the class, but it allows me to see the value on the column, but I cannot modify it (maybe there is something missing, like a "setAttribute" function)

What do you think?

Comment: Nothing strictly but you may need to add it into `rules()` and `attributeLabels()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add a column to a table, you need to mark this attribute at least as *safe* in model rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // other rules...
        [['yourNewColumn'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

and now this attribute will be consider safe for assigning value to it. Explicit declaration `public $columnname` not needed because yii2 parse table schema for existing fields